# SSMA for db2: unable to see schema table after connection

Tags: sql-server-migration-assi

[ssma table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HyxQ.png)

I'm trying to use SSMA for db2 to convert ibm I db2 file schemas to SQL Server 2022 schemas then migrate data. I successfully connect to ibm i db2 database. I can drill down to the file schema I want to convert in the metadata explorer (left window). When I highlight the file I want to convert to SQL Server, I should be able to see the file fields in the right window under the table tab. Does anyone know why I can’t see the db2 file field breakdown under the table tab?

I connected to ibm i db2 database and drilled down to table schema. i clicked on the table schema i wanted to convert expecting to see table fields and field formats (under the table tab) and table data (under the data tab). The table tab display was grey and the table data tab showed

> Unable to show data for the unloaded table for the following reason:

and did not show a reason.